# MongoError: Topology is closed, please connect after create new document

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I am having difficulties to perform some tasks in mongoose, I have a code in which right after creating a new entity I make a selection in another but when making this selection I run into the error

> MongoError: Topology is closed, please connect

firing events after saving

```js
if (this.emitter) {
    await this.emitter('pre_create', {entity});
}
let response = await this.entity_class.create(entity);
if (this.emitter) {
    await this.emitter('post_create', {entity: response});
}
```

select for another entity from another collection within the event

```js
 this.cache.account = await this.account_repository.find_one({
    name: account_name
});
```

as you can see I encapsulated the mongoose.